# GETTING THE ERROR "socket.io.js:3956 GET http://localhost:3030/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NfTGefc net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io-1.0

I am working on a video calling app and so when I am trying to stream my own video, I am getting the following error : socket.io.js:3956 GET http://localhost:3030/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NfTGefc net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I am also getting the warning : DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:3030/socket.io/socket.io.js.map: Connection error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My camera is working fine but still unable to stream the video. I tried various ways to fix this but haven't been able to fix this.
I am attaching the codes of the server file and other files

server.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const {v4: uuidv4}= require('uuid');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(`/${uuidv4()}`);
});

app.get('/:room', (req, res) => {
    res.render('room', {roomId: req.params.room})
})

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('join-room', (roomId)=> {
        console.log("joined room");
        socket.join(roomId);
        socket.on(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-connected');
    })
    
})
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


server.listen(3030);
```

script.js :

```
const socket = io('/');
const videoGrid = document.getElementById("video-grid");
const myVideo = document.createElement('video');
myVideo.muted = true;
let myVideoStream;
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true
}).then(stream => {
    myVideoStream = stream;

    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);

})

socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID);

socket.on('user-connected', ()=>{
    connecToNewUser();
})

const connecToNewUser = () => {
    console.log('new user');
}

const addVideoStream = (video, stream) => {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener('loadmetadata', ()=> {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.addEventListener('loadmetadata', () => {
            video.play();
        })
    })
    videoGrid.append(video);
}
```

room.ejs :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" ></script>
    <title>MS_Teams_Clone</title>
    <script>
        const ROOM_ID = ("<%= roomId %>");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="video-grid">

    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would be truly grateful if someone could help me fix this.
Thankyou

Comment: The warning means you aren't hosting the source maps where it expects to find them. You can safely ignore this for now.  The error means you have an issue with your server. Verify your protocol, port, running status, any intermediate web servers.